# How to remove all the rows and reset the listview in android without reloading activity in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

**What i have done**:: I have set images in listview  and on button click i have set the adapter

**What i am trying to do**:: On another button click i just want to remove all the images from the listview to and display empty list

---

**Mainclass i have called**

```
adapter = new AdptAddjobsGallery(getActivity(),listOfImages);
            lstHorizontalId.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**AdptAddjobsGallery.java**

```
public class AdptAddjobsGallery extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;

    private final ArrayList<String> listOfImages;

    public AdptAddjobsGallery(Activity context, ArrayList<String> listOfImages) {
        super(context, R.layout.adpt_addjobs_gallery, listOfImages);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

        this.context=context;
        this.listOfImages = listOfImages;

    }


    public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        try {
            if(view == null)
            {       
                LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
                view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.adpt_addjobs_gallery, null,true);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.selfie);
                //holder.txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fileName);
                view.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listOfImages.get(position));       
            File f = new File(listOfImages.get(position));  
            //holder.txtTitle.setText(f.getName());

            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(CommonFunctions.CompressImage(f));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;

    }


}

class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtTitle;
    ImageView imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call below code when delete button is clicked

```
listOfImages.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I tried that but i get : 12-28 18:03:29.692: E/AndroidRuntime(9563): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3 12-28 18:03:29.692: E/AndroidRuntime(9563): at com.windhyaworks.fragments.FrgAddNewJobs$4.onClick(FrgAddNewJobs.java:1304) 12-28 18:03:29.692: E/AndroidRuntime(9563): at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertControll‌​er.java:941)

Comment: I have used https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView .... for listview

Comment: i had only those two lines in `onclick` ..... is this because Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(listOfImages.get(position));       
            File f = new File(listOfImages.get(position));   .... if i pass empty it might cause any issue ?

Comment: try to put some image from resourse to imageview and check. bez clear wont cause any ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: Actually there was  problem was i was using wrong array in selection .... resolved !

Comment: oh man...if you have pasted the entire code, then this should be corrected earlier.

Answer (score 0):

try `adapter.clearAll()` or if you want to referesh your list item then use this one.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

When ever you update,remove your list item after then used above code,That referesh your adapter.

Comment: I tried that but i get : 12-28 18:03:29.692: E/AndroidRuntime(9563): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3 12-28 18:03:29.692: E/AndroidRuntime(9563): at com.windhyaworks.fragments.FrgAddNewJobs$4.onClick(FrgAddNewJobs.java:1304) 12-28 18:03:29.692: E/AndroidRuntime(9563): at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertControll‌​er.java:941)

Comment: I have used https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView .... for listview